# Gutter overfllowing

Tags: gutters

Our roof has a fairly complex geometry. In one spot, there is a downspout that empties into another gutter. It routinely overflows. We have covers on the gutters, but some really fine tree litter sticks around. I've got a couple of pics that show the issue best. I'll attach them. One shows the overflow from below, the other shows from above.

What do you recommend? Some sort of better junction where the water goes directly in to the lower gutter?[image]

Comment: Is it splashing out or overflowing?  The pipe outlet should be further up the roof, so the water can spread

Answer (score 1):

Either move the downspout left and empty it higher on the roof with a spreader or move it right and go straight to the ground,

Comment: Going to the ground is a better option to avoid wearing down the roofing shingles.

Comment: yeah I forgot that your shingles are basically just tar-soaked cardboard.

Answer (score 0):

You have one of two problems here.  Either the receiving gutter has a low (or even backpitched) slope, which causes standing water at the downspout in question.  Or there's a clog in the gutter or its downspout, causing a backup in the gutter.